# How to custom column export excel on Kendo UI MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to remove columns **columns.Bound(c => c.Id)** in excel when click button export. How to do that???

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
              .Name("listResult")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Index).Title(ResourceLabel.COMMON_SN);
                  columns.Bound(c => c._Type);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.__Name);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.S__Date);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Region);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Status);
                  columns.Bound(c => c._Name);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title("Action").ClientTemplate("<div class='form-inline action'>" +
                                                                          "#=RenderAction(data)#" +
                                                                          "</div>");
                  //columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title("Action").ClientTemplate("#=RenderAction(data)#");


              })
              .Pageable()
              .AutoBind(false)
              .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Excel())
              .Excel(excel => excel.FileName("P_File.xlsx")
              .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Save", "Search")))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [excelExport event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-excelExport) you can subscribe to that will allow you to hide columns before export. Looks like the MVC wrappers don't handle this directly, so you would need to configure your own jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myGrid = $("#listResult").data("kendoGrid");
    myGrid.excelExport = function(e) {
        myGrid.hideColumn(0);
    }
}
```